# Renormalized limit measure on a splitting Ricci limit space

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm reading Cheeger&Colding's *On the structure of spaces with Ricci curvature bounded below. I* recently. In the proof of proposition 1.35 as follows. I got some questions:

*Proposition 1.35. Let $\left\{\left(M_i^n, p_i\right)\right\} \rightarrow\left(Y^m, y\right)$ satisfy Ric $M_i^n \geq-\varepsilon_i$, where $\varepsilon_i \rightarrow 0$. If $Y^m$ splits isometrically, $Y^m=\mathbb{R} \times X$, then any limit measure, $\nu$, is a product measure, $\nu=\mathcal{H}_{\mathbb{R}}^1 \times \psi$, for some measure, $\psi$, on $X$.*

In the proof, it suffices to show that $$
\nu\left(B_r((-t, x))\right) \leq \nu\left(B_r((t, x))\right) .
$$
holds for any $t,x$.

The proof goes as follows:

*For $w \in B_r((-t, x))$, let $\gamma_s$ denote a minimal geodesic segment from $(s, x)$ to $w$. Let
$$
I_s=\left\{u \mid \gamma_s(u) \in B_r((-t, x))\right\}
$$
$$
J_s=\left\{u \mid \gamma_s(u) \in B_r((t, x))\right.
$$
and let $\left|I_s\right|,\left|J_s\right|$ denote the 1-dimensional measure of $I_s, J_s$, respectively. From the isometric splitting, $\mathbb{R} \times X$, it follows that for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $s(\varepsilon)$ such that for $s \geq s(\varepsilon)$, we have
$$
\left|J_s\right|+\varepsilon \geq\left|I_s\right|
$$

Clearly, the directionally restricted version of volume comparison holds for $\mu=\nu, k=n, H=0$. Therefore, by observing the ball, $B_r((-t, x))$, from the point, $(s, x)$, letting $s \rightarrow \infty$ and applying the formula above, we easily complete the proof.*

I wonder what's the directionally restricted version of volume comparison and how it's applied here. and what the sentence *by observing the ball, $B_r((-t, x))$, from the point, $(s, x)$, letting $s \rightarrow \infty$* means? Also, I wonder that whether there are some references about Cheeger-Colding theory in "On the structure of spaces with Ricci curvature bounded below. I,II,III". In fact, all the notes I found only give "alsmot splitting theorem" and "almost volume cone implies almost metric cone theorem". I want a reference which gives a complete introduction about Ricci limit spaces. Thanks in advance.